# I can't get ReactiveUI MessageBus to work on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, reactiveui

I'm trying to implement messaging between my ViewModels
My Proof of Concept Code is the following:

```
RxApp.MessageBus.Listen<int>("test")
    .Subscribe(i => MessageBox.Show(i.ToString()));    

RxApp.MessageBus.SendMessage<int>(42, "test");
```

My unit Tests run successfully so I thought it might be a Scheduling problem.
I manually set the Scheduler: `RxApp.DeferredScheduler = DispatcherScheduler.Instance;`

but it was set to the right Instance anyway so as expected, no change.
I can register for Messages. I just never receive any :/
Using an empty message contract does not change anything either.

I tried on both the Emulator and a Device (Mango SDK Refresh / Mango Build 7712)

I hope someone here can help me :)
Any hints are very much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My mistake, for assuming it was something non-trivial to do with the Scheduler :)

The problem was, that the Tuple class in use as a Dictionary key on WP7/SL does not implement a useful `Equals()` override.

The Dictionary never returned any matches when looking up the registered Subjects.

`GetHashCode()` should also be replaced with a custom implementation.

Comment: Its not obvious how this answer relates to the question.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is a MessageBus bug - who writes this crap, anyways?

** I'll look into it :)

Comment: I don't mean to nag, but i'm kind of on a deadline here ;)
I would love to use the MessageBus, but maybe I need to find a replacement...
Regardless, i'd like to help in finding a solution for the MessageBus if I can :)

Comment: Even if I fix it, making a release is a fairly time-consuming affair. MessageBus is actually just a single CS file, you could copy it and change it to do what you want (you can even name your implementation MessageBus2 then set RxApp.MessageBus)

Comment: I don't mean to leave you in the lurch, but just from a practical perspective, this is the quickest way for you to get unstuck

Comment: Against my expectations, it turned out to be within my powers to solve ;)
I sent you a pull request on Github with the fixes.